# How to show that a group is finite and also normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

Let $G$ be an finite group and $H$ normal subgroup of $G$. Show $\left|G\big/H\right|=\left|G\right|$ if and only if $H=\{e\}$.

Firstly I do not know how to show that $G$ is finite. Next I know that if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ then for all $a \in G$ I have the cosets $aH = Ha$.

Please help.

Comment: I'm a little confused: you state that $G$ is finite as a hypothesis, but then ask why it is finite?  Do you mean that you need to show that $G/H$ and $H$ are finite?

Comment: @Hayden , the question is "Let G be an finite group and H is a subgroup normal to G. PROVE That |G/H|=|H|if and only if H={e}". I do not know how to start it out.

Comment: do i have to how that G is finite??

Comment: I actually don't quite see why the statement is true.  If $H=\{e\}$, then $G/H\cong G$, so that $|G/H|=|G|$.  But since $H=\{e\}$, we have $|H|=1$, so that $|G/H|=|H|$ if and only if $G=\{e\}$.  Are you sure the question doesn't state "Prove that $|G/H|=|G|$ if and only if $H=\{e\}$"?

Comment: Um, $\mathbb{Z}_4$ has a subgroup $\langle 2 \rangle$ of order $2$, and $\mathbb{Z}_4/\langle 2 \rangle$ has order $2$.  Are you sure you don't mean $|G/H|=|G|$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are given a finite group $G$ and a normal subgroup $H$ of $G$, so you don't need to prove that $G$ is finite and that $H$ is normal.

Regarding the statement

> $\left|G\big/H\right|=\color{blue}{|G|}\quad$ if and only if $\quad H=\{e\}$

do you know Lagrange's theorem?

(Note: In your original question you wrote $\left|G\big/H\right|=\color{red}{\left|H\right|}$, I'm pretty sure that was a mistake.)

Comment: ,yes i made a mistake..thanks

Comment: @ christoph, can you check my attempt to see if am on the right track.

Comment: Let G be an finite group. Now we are to show that |G/H|=|G| if |H|={e}.To prove that H is the unit element. That is H=eH and gH\upvarepsilon|G/H| holds that eH * gH =(eg)H = gH and gH * eH = (ge)H =  gH. Now we are to established that all the element gH\upvarepsilon |G/H| has inverse, we show g inverse element of H and G=H. Since gH(g inverse)H = (g g inverse)H = eH = H and (g inverse)HgH = (g inverse g)H = eH = H completing the proof.

Comment: @Lynnie The things you stated in your comment are true for *every* normal subgroup, so you didn't say anything about $|G/H|=|G|\Leftrightarrow |H|=\{e\}$. Again, do you know Lagrange's theorem? If not, do you know that $G/H$ is a partition of $G$?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*: the cosets of $H$ in $G$ are disjoint, all have the same size, and the union of them is $G$.  Keep in mind that $H$ itself is a coset of $H$ in $G$.  $|G/H|$ is the number of cosets of $H$ in $G$.  If $|G/H|=|G|$, how big can the cosets be?